# EF Core 3.0 Manually setting connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core

I'm developing a console app with .NET Core & EF Core (both are v3.0); and I need to start my DbContext using an string generated from another class.

**DbContext file**

```
public Arta_LuniaDBContext() { }

public Arta_LuniaDBContext(DbContextOptions<Arta_LuniaDBContext> options) : base(options) { }

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
   optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(DataServices.ConnectionString);
}
```

**DataServices class**

```
public static string ConnectionString { get { return GetConnectionData(); } }

private static string GetConnectionData()
{
   /// Sets the Server name, Database, UserId and Password.
   string Server, Database, UserId, Password;

   /// Sets the separator.
   string Separator = ";";

   /// Connection string [internal].
   string ArtaConn = null;

   /// Loads Settings.xml
   XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
   xDoc.Load("Settings.xml");

   /// Gets the XmlNode: DataSource
   XmlNodeList xSource = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("DataSource");
   for (int i = 0; i < xSource.Count; i++)
   {
      /// Sets the Server name.
      Server = "Server=" + xSource[i].Attributes["Server"].Value + Separator;

      /// Sets the Database.
      Database = "Database=" + xSource[i].Attributes["Database"].Value + Separator;

      /// Sets the User id.
   UserId = "User id=" + xSource[i].Attributes["UserId"].Value + Separator;

      /// Sets the Password.
      Password = "Password=" + xSource[i].Attributes["Password"].Value + Separator;

      /// Builds the connection string.
      ArtaConn = Server + Database + UserId + Password;
      Colorful.Console.WriteLine(ArtaConn, System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);
      // I'm using this line to test the output.
   }

   /// Returns~
   return ArtaConn;
}
```

**Settings.xml**

```
<!-- Sets the Database ConnectionString -->
<DataSource Server="IP_ADDRESS\\INSTANCE" Database="DbName" UserId="MyUser" Password="MyPassword" />
```

ConsoleWrite line shows my output as:

```
Server=IP_ADDRESS\\INSTANCE;Database=DbName;User id=MyUser;Password=MyPassword;
```

And this string seems okay for me but, when I try to connect to the database, I'm getting the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26
>   - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Strange enough, if I set:

```
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("IP_ADDRESS\\INSTANCE;Database=DbName;User id=MyUser;Password=MyPassword;");
```

I can connect without any problem…

Is there any way to fix it? Thanks in advance.

[Edit] Fixed it;
Changed:

```
<DataSource Server="IP_ADDRESS\\INSTANCE" Database="DbName" UserId="MyUser" Password="MyPassword" />
```

To:

```
<DataSource Server="IP_ADDRESS\INSTANCE" Database="DbName" UserId="MyUser" Password="MyPassword" />
```

Comment: Did you provide the actual password here in your question?

Comment: If you want and easy solution that doesn't hardcode the connection string in your code, you can combine your 2 methods above by having a config variable store your hardcoded connection string, and then access that config variable in your call to optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer. Also, you really ought not to post your entire connection string (password included) onto this website for all to see!

Comment: Oops, fixed the connection password and details. :p

Comment: That password is still available in the history. Better change it.

Comment: you may be interested in this info: how to history removed.
Please also heed  @jdv : change the pwd.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86195/who-has-the-privilege-to-delete-a-revision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use right tool for the job  - [SqlConnectionStringBuilder Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)
Builder will escape backslashes and build proper connection string for Sql Server connection.

```
var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
{
    DataSource = @"IP_ADDRESS\INSTANCE",
    InitialCatalog = "DbName",
    UserID = "MyUserId",
    Password = "MyPassword"
};

var connectionString = builder.ConnectionString;

// Use connection string
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString );
```

So your method can look like below:

```
private SqlConnectionStringBuilder BuilderFromElement(XElement source)
{
    return new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
    {
        DataSource = source.Attribute("Server")?.Value,
        InitialCatalog = source.Attribute("Database")?.Value,
        UserID = source.Attribute("UserID")?.Value,
        Password = source.Attribute("Password")?.Value
    };
}

private string GetConnectionString()
{
    var settings = XDocument.Load("Settings.xml");
    var allConnectionStrings = 
        settings.Descendants("DataSource")
                .Select(BuilderFromElement)
                .Select(builder => builder.ConnectionString)
                
    return allConnectionStrings.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: OP is .net core 3.0?

Answer (score 1):

review the used of backslashes in your xml file.

in some contexts,  `\\` can be an escaped \, as a literal, it is 2 slashes.

This code illustrates the point: These string are not equal.

```
        String s= "Server=IP\\INSTANCE_NAME;Database=db;User id=User ;Password=pwd;";
    String s2= @"Server=IP\\INSTANCE_NAME;Database=db;User id=User ;Password=pwd;";

    Console.WriteLine(s2== s);
```

If you try this with localhost, does it work the way you expect? 
if so: the culpurit is the .

you can also see if this works.

```
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=Server=IP\\INSTANCE_NAME;Database=DB;User id=User ;Password=pwd;");
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Omg~ I've changed it in my XML; Server="IP_ADDRESS\\INSTANCE" to Server="IP_ADDRESS\INSTANCE"; and it's working now.

Thanks @brian chandley